# Spring JPA/Hibernate: Failed to import bean definitions

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

Beating my head against the wall for hours and can't resolve this issue, seems to be either a mistake in my config setup or maybe a dependency conflict or missing dependency. Any thoughts?

**Relevant dependencies:**

```
Spring Data Commons Core 1.2.0
Spring Data JPA 1.8.0
Hibernate Core 5.0
Hibernate JPA 2.1
```

**Error message in Eclipse:**

```
Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [SpringDbContext.xml] Offending resource: class path resource [SpringAppContext.xml]; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 43 in XML document from class path resource [SpringDbContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd; lineNumber: 43; columnNumber: 63; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
```

**SpringAppContext.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <import resource="SpringWebContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="SpringDbContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="SpringSecurityContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="SpringSocialContext.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.metagravy.ark.security"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="i18n/messages"/>
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Hibernate configs:**

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.show_sql=false
```

**SpringDbContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.metagravy.ark"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.metagravy.ark.security"/>


</beans>
```

Comment: Try including the `xsd` for `spring-repository`, i.e. `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.8.xsd`, since that's where `auditing-attributes` is defined.

Comment: Are you using the Spring Data release trains for dependency management? If not you probably have some conflicting dependencies.

Comment: A dependency conflict was the issue. Upgraded spring-data-commons to v1.10 and am now tracking down new errors.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help, I upgraded spring-data-commons from 1.2 to 1.10 and it resolved the error.

Comment: May want to give this answer a check mark so the question is removed from the list of unanswered questions